# How to grep just strings "ip" into a file?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to find every way to find a string in some text. I want to find more ways using grep or sed. (bear in mind It's case sensitive)

- Every word  (strings) containing string "ip" and redirect the output result in /root/found;

```
 grep ip /usr/share/dict/words/ > /root/found
```

- Just words (strings) initiating with "ip"  and redirect the output result in /root/found;

```
 grep ^ip  /usr/share/dict/words > /root/found
```

- Just the word "ip" and redirect the output result in /root/found;

```
grep ^ip$ /usr/share/dict/words > /root/found
```

Comment: I'm not clear on why you "want to find more ways". Are the ways you tried not working as expected? Is this purely for academic purposes? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes It's for academic purposes, I should clarify in the question. After the answers I will trace/test every answer and find out which one consumes more resources. The answer from Steephen make me have other ideas. I will qualify the students answers by: completeness, less resource consumption, creativity. Sometimes I got some strange minds at classroom. I would like to understand the gaps between the students.

Comment: This belongs on Superuser or Linux&Unix network, I reckon.

Comment: Elyasin I am sorry. It will not happen again. You are totally right.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to append output into file /root/found  instead using `>` you have to use `>>`

Grep over irrespective of case:

```
grep -i "ip" /ust/share/dict/words >> /root/found
```

If you want to search all  files in sub directories and current directories of /ust/share/dict/words

```
find /ust/share/dict/words -name "*" -exec grep "ip"  '{}' \; -print  >> /root/found
```

Comment: Steephen. The second answer has a awkward result: the file was created but no inputs were done. mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6d29be0000
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [CHLD], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f6d29166a00}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6d29c22ad0) = 3813
wait4(3813,